# Linux file locking in C - Can flock() be mandatory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, file-locking

As a C rookie I was just reading about locks and saw [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/linux-file-locking-types/) that it is possible to enable mandatory locking in Linux to use with `fcntl()`. Is it possible to use other locking functions like `flock()` as mandatory locks?

Answer (score 1):

No.

If the semantics of `flock()` changed, all programs that rely on these locks being advisory would break.